# Count cells dynamically in macro

Tags: excel, vba

What can I replace in:

```
Set Rng = Sheets("Annual SnD Raw Data").Range("J2:J89500")
```

In order for `Rng` to be the range from `J2` the last used used cell in column `J`?

I tried:

```
Sheets("Annual SnD Raw Data").Range(Cells(2, 10), Cells(2, Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA("J:J")))
```

But it didn't set the correct range.

Comment: Wait - do you want `Rng` to be a single cell, or the range from `J2` through the last used cell in the column?

Comment: The range. Edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
With Sheets("Annual SnD Raw Data")
    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2,10),.Cells(.Rows.Count,10).End(xlUp))
End With
```

Comment: No idea how VBA works but this answer worked for me and the other answer didn't (almost certainly on account of some ambiguity in my question). If you could maybe explain the differences? If not thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Bruce's answer only selects the last cell, where mine selects the whole range.  He misunderstood what you were asking.  If you do not understand the `With Sheets("Annual SnD Raw Data")` look up `With Block VBA` on google.  there are a lot of sites that explain how and why it should be used.  It basically is a short cut so I did not need to write it out 3 times.

Comment: @RafaelMartins Bruce's answer was written in response to the original question, which said "In order for Rng to be the last used cell in column J".

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.End(xlUp)`:

```
Set Rng = Sheets("Annual SnD Raw Data").Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
```

Comment: @ScottCraner - I went for speed, you went for thoroughness :P